# Implementing Content Provider: compound primary key

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm implementing my own Content Provider because I'm gonna synchronize my database with a server. My data is stored in a SQLiteDatabase, and some of my tables have a compound primary key (2 columns, each one a foreign key to another table).

I just started working with Content Providers and I don't know much how they work, but as I could see googling a bit I need to define the name of the tables and their primary key:

```
uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "books", BOOKS);
uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "books/#", BOOK_ID);
```

As I understand it, if I use the URI .../books/1 it would access the Book with primary key "1". The thing is, does it work with a compund primary key? If it does, how would the URI be?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm implementing my own Content Provider because I'm gonna synchronize my database with a server.

You do not need to use a `ContentProvider` to synchronize a database with a server.

> The thing is, does it work with a compund primary key?

Not readily. Quoting [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html):

> Table data should always have a "primary key" column that the provider maintains as a unique numeric value for each row.

You could to add a separate column (typically named `_id`) that you will use for the `ContentProvider` as the primary key. If you use an `AUTOINCREMENT` column, you will not ever have to assign a value yourself, meaning that you can ignore this column in pretty much all respects except where `ContentProvider` wants an instance `Uri`.

You are welcome to attempt to avoid this, and use a `Uri` that looks like `content://your.authority.goes.here/table/key1/key2` or something like that. However, it will not work with `CursorAdapter` and various other places in the framework may assume the numeric ID pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. About needing a ContentProvider, I'm using AbstractThreadSyncAdapter and the guide I'm following said that this way needs a ContentProvider, that's why I'm implementing it.